# How to increase the size of the input in lucee

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

What is the reason behind this following issue, how to increase the size of the input in lucee. I don't know what I do. Please help me.
I knew how to increase that in Coldfusion. In Coldfusion we use **server settings-Request Size Limits**

***lucee.runtime.exp.NativeException: The input was too large. The specified input was 15,307 bytes and the maximum is 15,000 bytes.***

Comment: Is this a file upload restriction?  Does this reference help? [FILE UPLOAD RESTRICTIONS IN LUCEE](https://www.webtrenches.com/file-upload-restrictions-in-lucee/)

Comment: @Miguel-F, Thanks for your reply. but, as per your link will use only for IIS. I using lucee installer. So, I can't see any web.config file in my local. Could you please share Where I use that code. 
<system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>

Comment: Guys, anyone please share your comments? if possible. It is one of the urgent issues.

Comment: \\lucee\tomcat\conf\server.xml ?

Comment: @Shawn, it doesn't work.